# parse the logical operator in excel and apply to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, logical-operators

Say we have an excel/csv file with a formula column that contains some logical operations that will resemble that you would do hard coded way in python. But instead we want to do modify/define them in excel so it would be just open excel and modify the formula as needed or add additional conditions.

I need to add a boolean column to my dataframe when all these conditions satisfied

1. The `GOOD` is larger than value in that is defined in excel file.
2. The `BAD` is smaller than value in that is defined in excel file.
3. The `UGLY` is not `nan`.

These conditions are defined in excel file's `formula` column.

test.xlsx

```
col1    value   Formula
GOOD    100     GOOD > value
BAD     50      BAD < value
UGLY    pd.isna pd.isna(UGLY)
```

df

```
       GOOD  BAD UGLY
    0   101   60    0
    1    22   61    0
    2   103   62
    3   104   63    0
```

So I tried this below to evaluate the Formula column from `test.xlsx` and apply them to `df`

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl

def create_dataframe():
    df = pd.DataFrame({'GOOD': [101,22,103,104],
                      'BAD': [60,61,62,63],
                      'UGLY': [0,0,'',0],

                      })
    print(df)
    read_filter = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')
    formulas = []
    for filter_col in read_filter['col1']:
       #print(read_filter['Formula'])
       formulas.append(read_filter['Formula'] + " and") 
    print(formulas)
    df['Result'] = df.apply(lambda x: eval(formulas) , axis=1)
    return df
```

The part I can't figure out how to parse/apply Formula(s) to my df. Any idea to how to accomplish this?

The expected output

```
   GOOD  BAD UGLY  Result
0   101   60    0   False
1    22   61    0   False
2   103   62        True    
3   104   63    0   False
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: `eval` is not a good choice for things coming from user input.  It is too dangerous.  It wouldn't be hard to parse a limited set of constructs and do it in a safe way.

Comment: @TimRoberts there is a problem with doing it in a hard coded way but what you are saying is to separate the Formula to three different columns and join them again in python ?

Comment: I'm just suggesting that you support a limited set of expressions, and parse it yourself.  You can't just do `eval`, because there is no variable called "GOOD".

Comment: @TimRoberts "GOOD" is in col 1 1st row :) And other formula values as well. I though people are smart to see that.

Comment: Yes, of course I know that, but your boolean expression is "GOOD < value".  If you use `eval` on that, there is no variable called GOOD for it to find.  You will HAVE to parse it in some way.